# Is Banner missing the tooth that Hulk lost?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-incredible-hulk, avengers-age-of-ultron

[image: Hulk spitting out tooth]

Stark's Hulkbuster armor manages to knock a tooth out of Hulk's mouth in Age of Ultron. Did this tooth simply regenerate, or is Banner missing it as well? It's clearly not a front tooth, because we see Banner apparently none the worse for wear in that regard afterwards.

Is there anything in the comics supporting this, or anything else that mentions it? If the question were broadly "what happens to banner when Hulk loses a tooth", the answer is clearly 'nothing', but the cinematic representation of Hulk's abilities is significantly different than what is portrayed in the comics and elsewhere. This question refers specifically to the Hulk in Age of Ultron and not elsewhere.

Comment: Given Hulk's insane regeneration, unless he transformed back to Banner within the next minute, I can't see it impacting him.  That said, I'm basing it on other media, as I've not seen the movies.

Comment: Yeah, I would totally agree, except that the tooth-spitting is generally cinematic shorthand that someone has been seriously and permanently injured (and thus the gloves are about to really come off). If that's not the case, what's the point of the shot?

Comment: Honestly?  Drama.  It shows that physical damage was done to the Hulk.. Not an easy thing to do.  But I think, for the hulk, it was closer to when a character reaches a hand up and wipes a drop of blood from the side of their mouth -- it shows they were hurt slightly... and now they are really mad.

Comment: Yeah, that's a closely related trope. My favorite invocation of that is in Dumb and Dumber :).

Comment: @Möoz - OP seems to be asking specifically about the AoU film

Comment: @Valorum But asking for comic sources. I'm satisfied that this is not different enough to warrant its own post.

Comment: I'm referring to comics which specifically are part of the MCU timeline. I remember recently there was a question about how Hulk ended up where he was in Ragnarok that was answered thusly.